# Hiding wordpress message using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to hide wordpress "please notify the site administrator" message from Dashboard.
[image]
The message is:

```
WordPress 3.5.1 is available! Please notify the site administrator.
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="update-nag"><a href="http://codex.wordpress.org/Version_3.5.1">WordPress 3.5.1</a> is available! Please notify the site administrator.</div>
```

So, i have added a css like this to hide the message but the this is not working!
Here is the css:

```
.update-nag{
display: none;}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? I'm curious to see if it requires both the ID an class name to be set to `display: none;`

Comment: yes, i have tried your code but it no works...

Comment: Strange, it works for me when I edit it in the inspector. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can sue this module found from [Prijm](http://www.prijm.com/) enable the module, will do the job:
[Hide Update Reminder Message](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hide-update-reminder-message/)

Answer (score 1):

Place the below code in your theme functions.php file.

Just put this simple code in your functions.php and the update message will be hidden.

```
function hideUpdateNag() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
add_action('admin_menu','hideUpdateNag');
```

Comment: add_action('admin_menu','wphidenag');
2
function wphidenag() {
3

Try this
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
4
}

Comment: Just put this simple code in your functions.php and the update message will be hidden.

    function hideUpdateNag() {
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
    }
    add_action('admin_menu','hideUpdateNag');

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#update-nag, .update-nag{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add_action('admin_menu','wphidenag');
2
function wphidenag() {
3
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
4
}

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Just put this simple code in your functions.php and the update message will be hidden.

```
function hideUpdateNag() {
    remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
add_action('admin_menu','hideUpdateNag');
```

Answer (score 0):

As the admin, I wanted to see the message, but I wanted it hidden for other users.  I did this:

```
function hideUpdateNag() {
    // if not an administrator
    if ( !current_user_can('update_core') ) {
        remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
    }

}
add_action('admin_menu','hideUpdateNag');
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Dashboard (admin world) items cannot be updated using CSS in the Customizer. That only affects front-end CSS. You must use functions, or a plugin/functions combination.

See this article for a solution that doesn't involve hacking functions in WP:
https://chriseller.com/how-to-remove-items-from-the-wordpress-admin-top-bar/